# onDraw in the background of a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that displays a list of media content (messages, images, videos, etc). I need to draw a line from one item to another (behind every item in the list). I though the easiest way would be to extend RecyclerView and override onDraw but onDraw never seems to be called.

I don't think `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` would do what I need because I need to draw within the bounds of the children of the view but behind every item in the list.

What is the best way to draw the background of a `RecyclerView`?

Comment: what is "behind everything",do you mean under every item?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: so item_decoration work perfectly :) or provide your expected view to make yoủ question more clearly

Comment: I haven't tried ItemDecorator but I have a suspicion that when drawing it the canvas will be clipped to only the size of the decorator. Meaning I wouldn't be able to draw withing the bounds of the other elements. For now I extended RecyclerView and Overrode drawChild. That seems to work.

Comment: great!!! have a nice day